# Assigning df vector to variable within shiny renderPlot

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a shiny app that creates a plot of two variables in my df. The user has the option to select X and Y, and then a check box option for logging X and one for logging Y. I have a working code for this, but I'm trying to simplify it. To do this, I want to assign the user's X variable to 'Independent' and the user's Y variable to 'Dependent' and then create an if statement that would account for Independent and Dependent being logged, so that I can carry on with my plot code just referring to the variables Independent and Dependent. Here's the code I have to illustrate what I mean, but the plot is not appearing in my app. I'm assuming I've used reactive() incorrectly:

```
 output$Plot <- renderPlot({
   
  reactive({
    
    if (input$xLog) { # check box for log(X)
      
    Independent <-  log(df[[input$Var1]])
    
    } else if (!input$xLog) {
      
    Independent <- df[[input$Var1]]
    
  }

     if (input$yLog) { # check box for log(Y)
       
       Dependent <-  log(df[[input$Var2]])
       
     } else if (!input$yLog) {
       
       Dependent <- df[[input$Var2]]
     }
     
plot <- ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = Independent, y = Dependent))

   }) end reactive()

plot <- plot + geom_point()

plot

}) # end renderPlot
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In your `ggplot` command, Independent and Dependent should be column names of `df`  for this to work. So either rename them, generate a transformed new df, or do something like `ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=Independent, y=Dependent))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues with your code:

- you don't need a `reactive` within `renderPlot` as this is already a reactive
- generate a data.frame for `ggplot` which contains the variables you reference in `aes`

```
output$Plot <- renderPlot({
  
  if (input$xLog) { # check box for log(X)
    
    Independent <-  log(df[[input$Var1]])
    
  } else {
    
    Independent <- df[[input$Var1]]
    
  }
  
  if (input$yLog) { # check box for log(Y)
    
    Dependent <-  log(df[[input$Var2]])
    
  } else {
    
    Dependent <- df[[input$Var2]]
  }
  
  plot_data <- data.frame(
    Independent = Independent,
    Dependent = Dependent
  )
  
  plot <- ggplot(plot_data = df,
                 mapping = aes(x = Independent, y = Dependent)) +
    geom_point()
  
  plot
  
}) # end renderPlot
```